# Can you form a Riemann surface with an uncountable infinity of complex planes?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Heuristically the Riemann surface of the logarithm is a countable infinity of complex planes attached one to the other. I wonder, is there any Riemann surface (or anything related) that consists of an uncountable infinity of complex planes sewn together?

Comment: Not if you insist that your Riemann surface is connected: all connected Riemann surfaces are second-countable.

Comment: This is [Radó's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rad%C3%B3%27s_theorem_(Riemann_surfaces)).